# UIAlertView in Swift, getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

First and foremost, I'm quite aware that Xcode 6 and the Swift language are in Beta and are prone to errors; however, this particular one seems to be something strange as everything else I've tried so far seems to work fine.

If this is not appropriate for StackOverflow, I will gladly remove the question.

I've begin playing with Xcode 6/Swift (preparing for its release) and it has been an extraordinarily enjoyable experience compared to what I thought it would be. That being said, one issue in porting a "training" style app I like to do is that I can't seem to generated a UIAlertView due to `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` the code in question is:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Title", message: "Message", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK") // EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
    alert.show()
}
```

On the line that creates the UIAlertView I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` because `[UIAlertView retain]` was called on a deallocated instance.

Again, I'm chalking this up to the beta banner but was curious if I was doing something wrong or if anyone else has run into similar issues.

Comment: IMHO it's a bug that should be reported.

Comment: @Sulthan You wouldn't happen to know where to report Swift bugs? I didn't see a place devoted to that.

Comment: I can't find a good category on https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try the following code

```
let alert = UIAlertView()
alert.title = "Title"
alert.message = "My message"
alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
alert.show()
```

But in iOS 8

`UIAlertView` is deprecated. So use `UIAlertController` with a `preferredStyle` of `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert`. It should be:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Check the above code, are you getting same error or not ?

Comment: Okay thanks. Two things, the first bit is not something I would have tried, and it works great. The second part is also not something I'd looked at yet (iOS 8 specifically, just wanted to jump in with Swift). Interesting information.

Comment: I'm not finding any indication that UIAlertView is deprecated.  I am seeing that UIAlertController is only iOS 8.  In fact, when I type the following in an Xcode editor (or a playground), I don't get a deprecated warning:

`let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()`

Can you post any reference to the depreciation?

Answer (score 1):

From Xcode 6.0 UIAlertView class:

> UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle
>   of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead.

On swift ( iOS 8 and OS X 10.10 ), you can do this:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "Send",
    message: "You have successfully send your feedback.",
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert
)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
    title: "Ok",
    style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
    handler: nil
))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -4):

2 things
u have to use delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle ends with nil

Comment: delegate is an optional type (`UIAlertViewDelegate?`) and you mean `otherButtonTitles` I imagine.