# UIAlertView is Not Working in Swift

Tags: ios, uialertview, swift

when i runt this code in swift, i dont know why the app terminates by showing a break point in the "alertView.show()" part, Somebody please help me.

```
var alertView = UIAlertView(
    title: "Hey",
    message: "Hello",
    delegate: self,
    cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel"
)
alertView.show()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From Xcode 6.0 UIAlertView class:

> UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle
>   of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead.

On swift ( iOS 8 and OS X 10.10 ), you can do this:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "Alert Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler:handleCancel))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in
                println("User click Ok button")
            }))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

func handleCancel(alertView: UIAlertAction!)
        {
            println("User click cancel button")
        }
```

If you want to use in 'ActionSheet' instead 'Alert' you need only to change the UIAlertControllerStyle for example:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "Alert Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i add a TextField to it.??

Comment: @AppleKid,add  alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configurationTextField),      and the function:                                                             func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        println("configurat hire the TextField")
        
        if let tField = textField {
            
            self.textField = textField!
            self.textField.text = "Hello world"
        }
    }  
Now you can to print the user's input on the handleCancel or handleOk closures: println(self.textField.text)

Comment: Trying to use self.textField.text in the closure but it says `Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit`

Answer (score 1):

UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS 8, But Swift supports iOS7 and you can not use UIAlertController on iOS 7.
Add the following method to solve the issue :

```
func showAlert(title:NSString, message:NSString,owner:UIViewController) {
    if let gotModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        owner.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else {
        let alertView = UIAlertView(title: title, message: message, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: "OK")
        alertView.alertViewStyle = .Default
        alertView.show()
    }
}
```

and call the method anywhere from the code like this :

```
showAlert(APP_NAME,message: "Add your alert message here" ,owner: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way for me is...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {
var allarme = UIAlertView(title: "Warning", message: "This is a best way to create a alarm message", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        allarme.show()
```

remember to import on the class UIAlertViewDelegate

Answer (score -1):

Use following way :

```
var altMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "This is Alert Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
altMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(altMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: use " func showInView(_ view: UIView!) " to add textField here is ref. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/showInView:

Comment: i didnt get it.. can you please show me a small code.??