# AlertViewController should not be dismissed when I enter empty AlertView textfield in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios9

I have added a textfield in AlertViewController. I don't type anything in the textfield and enter the OK button meaning dismiss the alert view. How should I check the alert textfield length is zero so that alert button actions are disabled. Please help me...

Comment: initially you can disable the button and Using UITextFieldDelegate method public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {} you can disable/enable the button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent dismissal of UIAlertController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25628000/prevent-dismissal-of-uialertcontroller)

Comment: How can you have objective-c and swift tagged? Which one are you using for this?

Comment: Also check out Guy Kahlons answer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093612/how-to-add-a-textfield-to-uialertview-in-swift ... it might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  AlertControllerDemo
//
//  Created by Nilesh on 8/10/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Nilesh. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong)UIAlertAction *okAction;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)showAlertButtonAction:(id)sender {

    self.okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay"
                                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                           handler:nil];
    self.okAction.enabled = NO;

    UIAlertController *controller = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                        message:@"Please Enter your text"
                                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [controller addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {

        textField.delegate = self;
    }];

    [controller addAction:self.okAction];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSString *finalString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self.okAction setEnabled:(finalString.length >= 1)];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

[image: Before Entering Text]
[image: After Entering Text]