# Preloaded text in an alert

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text, alert

I was wondering if it was possible to have an alert with preloaded text in it. For example, if my app guessed something I would want the guess to appear in the alert text box but the user could delete the text and change the answer if they wanted to.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at this page : [How to add a TextField to UIAlertView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093612/how-to-add-a-textfield-to-uialertview-in-swift) ?

You could put textfields (or anything else you'd like) inside the alertview and so that the user could interact with it more deeply :)

Vincent

Comment: @Anon4321 my pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. You can create a custom alertView from a xib and you can input there an UITextField ,so the user can have the opportunity to change the text

Comment: I don't think he needs any kind nib, You can add a textfield directly to the alert controller

Comment: yes of course, i was saying if he wants it more custom anyway both solutions are valuable

Comment: have you tried to create custom class for alerting/? and put it to viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 0):

Simply Create an alert controller leave the title and message empty and add a TextField to your alert that way you can preload your text to the TextField and user can also edit the text

Answer (score 0):

Just add text field in alert controller.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "please enter words", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (txtUsername) -> Void in
     usernameTextField?.text = "preload"
     usernameTextField?.placeholder = "placeholder"

 }

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```