# Alert error in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I writing this code in swift and Xcode 6

```
@IBAction func Alert(sender : UIButton) {
  var alert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Hey", message: "This is  one Alert",       delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Working!!")

    alert.show()
}
```

Xcode doesn't show error in compilation.

but in Simulator the APP fails and return the error:

```
(lldb)
thread 1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1 address=0x20)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: i find the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24084521/uialertview-is-not-working-in-swift

Answer (score 46):

There is a bug in the Swift shim of the UIAlertView convenience initializer, you need to use the plain initializer

```
let alert = UIAlertView()
alert.title = "Hey"
alert.message = "This is  one Alert"
alert.addButtonWithTitle("Working!!")
alert.show()
```

This style code feels more true to the Swift Language. The convenience initializer seems more Objective-C'ish to me. Just my opinion.

Note: UIAlertView is **deprecated** (see declaration) but Swift supports iOS7 and you can not use UIAlertController on iOS 7

**View of UIAlertView Declaration in Xcode**

```
// UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of   UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
class UIAlertView : UIView {
```

**An Alert in Swift iOS 8 Only**

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "This is  one Alert", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Working!!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Update for Swift 4.2**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "This is  one Alert", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Working!!", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```