# why UIAlertController in iOS7 received nil value?

Tags: ipad, ios7, ios8, uialertcontroller

why UIAlertController in iOS7 received nil value while need to presented but worked in iOS8 was good, may i know that is because iOS7 not support the UIAlertController class ?

```
UIAlertController *view=[UIAlertController
                        alertControllerWithTitle:@"Hello"
                        message:nil
                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

 [self presentViewController:view animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: UIAlertController was introduced for iOS 8. It wont work in iOS7. For iOS7 you should use UIAlertView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111011/uialertview-uialertcontroller-ios-7-and-ios-8-compatibility

Comment: I have created a simple wrapper class that can be used with both. It mimics the UIAlertController. https://github.com/Reggian/RAAlertController

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These class is only available in iOS8 and later. See the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

In order to display `AlertView` in both `iOS 8` and lower versions you can use the following code:

```
if ([self isiOS8OrAbove]) {
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                             message:message
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                                     }];

    [alertController addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                         message:message
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)isiOS8OrAbove {
    NSComparisonResult order = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion compare: @"8.0"
                                                                       options: NSNumericSearch];
    return (order == NSOrderedSame || order == NSOrderedDescending);
}
```

Comment: but i think do check on classes is better than check on the system version ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using os version less then **iOS 8**.

If you compile your code with Xcode 6 and use a device with iOS version < 8.0 then you will face this issue. I would suggest the following

```
- (void)showXYZAlert
{
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
    {
        // Handle UIAlertController
        [self showXYZAlertController];
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle UIAlertView
        [self showXYZAlertControllerView];
    }
}
```