# How to use UIAlertView with iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, xcode6

I am using AlertView since release of iOS8,but after release of iOS8 UIAlertView is replaces by UIAlertViewController. Then how to use it as a UIAlertView.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. can you give us a bit more information? Also please edit your question and add the code that you tried to get it to work, and explain what the error was you got (include any relevant logfile entries if you have it). Also tell us what research you've done on the subject (so we don't duplicate your effort). Thanks

Comment: http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111011/uialertview-uialertcontroller-ios-7-and-ios-8-compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlertView in Swift in ios8

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertController * myAlert=   [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                message:@"put a message here"
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[self presentViewController:MyAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([UIAlertController class])
{
    // use UIAlertController
    UIAlertController *alert= [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Folder Name"
                                  message:@"Keep it short and sweet"
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                   //Do Some action here


                                               }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                       NSLog(@"cancel btn");

                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                                   }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [alert addAction:cancel];



    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

use this code

Comment: this one is helpful.