# Swift - How do you DECIDE the optimal "Deployment Target" for your iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

On Xcode, you can decide the "Deployment Target" by yourself, but you may choose too old version to run the app stably since some of methods in your code are supported by later version of iOS.
(e.g. choose Deployment Target 8.0, but when you run the app on a device with iOS version 8.0, the app crashes)

Is there any good way to decide the best Deployment Target, or some tools which can scan the whole code to know the minimum version of iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats actually a new feature of `Xcode 7` and `Swift 2.0` see from swift website:

[Swift Apple](https://developer.apple.com/swift/)

On the website it states, under `Availability`

> Swift 2.0 has built-in availability checking to make it easy to build the best possible app for each target OS version. The compiler will give you an error when using an API too new for your minimum target OS

Comment: right, but there are some issues like below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111011/uialertview-uialertcontroller-ios-7-and-ios-8-compatibility so I want to know better way if there is any.

Comment: @stackgk thats exactly what Xcode 7 will point out to you, start a new project in Xcode 7 set the target to 7.0 and then in the main `ViewController` create the `UIAlertController` and see the error you get from Xcode as well as a suggestion on how to fix it.