# How to find out what your deployment target should be

Tags: xcode, deployment-target

I've always wondered how to correctly determine your deployment target for an app. I am using Sprite kit in objective-c so I guessing my deployment target should be roughly 7.0. Would it be correct to find your deployment target by testing different deployment targets on your device to make sure everything functions correctly? or is there an easier way to determine your deployment target?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you are using Swift 2.0 take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/31720554/3402095

Comment: So would this would for objective-c in xcode 7? If not do you know of another way? Thanks

Comment: Its Swift 2.0 only feature. The other way would be probably using Deploymate OS X app (haven't tried it by myself). You can read about it here : http://www.raywenderlich.com/42591/supporting-multiple-ios-versions-and-devices Also, I that link will probably answer to Obj-C part of your question.