# UINavigationItem Title Perform Action

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, storyboard, swift

What is a good way to get a popup to appear (specifically a date picker) when I tap the title of my navigation bar? I'm actually using xcode6/swift but assume an ios7 solution would suffice!

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set button as `title view`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var button:UIButton  = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

    (button as UIView).frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)
    button.setTitle("Your title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = button;
}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{

    UIAlertView(title: "Message title", message: "POP UP", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()

}
```

**Edit** `UIAlertView` deprecated in iOS8.Using `UIAlertViewController` instead

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{

  var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
 alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
 self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for your help. This also taught me how to make popups appear which is great. Is there a way to add a UIDatePicker into the UIAlertView?

Comment: You can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166734/add-uidatepicker-to-uialertview

Comment: Use alertView.setValue(customContentView,"accessoryView") here you `customContentView` is your date picker

Comment: Oh one other thing - it actually seems to crash on UIAlertView (BAD_INSTRUCTION). is there something else I need to do for the uialertview to function? thanks so much!

Comment: are you using same code that i have posted in answer??

Comment: Yeah same code. What do you think? A lot of people are saying it has to do with doing this in main thread does that have something to do with it?

Comment: it is working fine.Nothing to do with threading here as it will execute on main thread as i posted.If you aree doing something diffrent than i have to look that Can you please give me where getting error

Comment: someone wrote it is deprecated in swift and you do it this way in ios8 ? I tried and it works now, although it jus t makes a popup (still interested in how I can make a date picker but I can start to work on that next) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029768/uialertview-in-swift-getting-exc-bad-access

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a button with the specific action on touch up inside and then define titleView for navigationItem:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = yourButton;
```

Now you have "touchable" navigation title.

Comment: ok thank you - so the idea is everything here happens dynamically (the popup, the date picker, and even the button.. all are instantiated with code) right?